# Sympy: Is it possible to use the Idx range to automatically evaluate Piecewise expressions?

Tags: python, indexing, sympy, piecewise

I want to define indexes over finite ranges that eliminate ambiguity in Piecewise expressions.

For instance:

```
from sympy import *
x = IndexedBase('x')
n = Symbol('n', nonnegative = True, integer = True)
k = Idx('k', (1, n))
f = 1/sqrt(Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n)))
j  = Idx('j', (1,n))
diff = diff(f,x[j])
```

`print(diff.simplify())` returns:

```
-Piecewise((x[j], n >= j), (0, True))/Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n))**(3/2)
```

However, I already declared, when defining `j`, that n>=j, and I would expect `x[j]` in the numerator instead of the Piecewise expression. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Without simplify, it uses `KroneckerDelta` which is neater than what you got.

Answer (score 0):

Why use index j? It seems to confuse the simplification algorithm.

Instead, using index k for differentiation, it returns the expected
result, without the spurious Piecewise split:

```
from sympy import *

x = IndexedBase('x')
n = Symbol('n', nonnegative = True, integer = True)
k = Idx('k', (1, n))
f = 1/sqrt(Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n)))
diff = diff(f, x[k])
print(str(diff.simplify()))
```

Output:

```
# -Sum(x[k], (k, 1, n))/Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n))**(3/2)
```

Comment: I am afraid your output is not the expected result. It should be 
`-x[k]/Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n))**(3/2)`.
I want to differentiate with respect to some specific `k`. What your code is doing is total differentiation with respect to all `k`, i.e., differentiating the function for all `k` in the range and then summing all these derivatives. This is what I was trying to avoid by using the third index, `j`